# EXPO - ‘exp fetch:ios:certs’ && 'exp: build:ios'

Tags: expo, exp

I’m currently trying to deploy a new build with “sdkVersion”: “25.0.0”, however I’m having many issues.

I have an Admin account on the Apple Enterprise Program.

Installed exp -g correctly, did 'exp login', and my app.json file is configured this way:

`{
  "expo": {
    "name": "AppName",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icon": "./app/assets/AppName.png",
    "slug": "AppName",
    "sdkVersion": "25.0.0",
    "privacy": "unlisted",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./app/assets/AppName.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover"
    },
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.group.AppName"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.group.AppName"
    }
  }
}`

When I try to do run exp build:ios I let Expo handle all credentials but in the end I get the following error:

> [exp] Error while gathering & validating credentials
>
> [exp] {}
>
> [exp] Reason:You are not allowed to perform this operation.  Please check with one of your Team Admins, or, if you need further assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program Support. https://developer.apple.com/support You are not allowed to perform this operation.  Please check with one of your Team Admins, or, if you need further assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program Support. https://developer.apple.com/support

I am admin so I really don’t know what this could refer to.

If I try specifying my own p12 Dist and Push certificates then I get this kind of error:

> [exp] Error while gathering & validating credentials
>
> [exp] {}
>
> [exp] Reason:No cert available to make provision profile against, raw:"Make sure you were able to make a certificate prior to this step"

And if I try running the command exp fetch:ios:certs I get the following error:

> [exp] Retreiving iOS credentials for @community/AppName
>
> [exp] Unable to fetch credentials for this project. Are you sure they exist?

I would greatly appreciate some guidance, I think I am doing something wrong but don’t know what it is.

Answer (score 3):

Even though exp was correctly creating the missing distribution certificates and push certificates for me, it was somehow having a hard time with the provisioning profile. After numerous trials, what worked was to create my certificates and the provisioning profile. Then choose the 'I will provide all the credentials and files needed, Expo does limited validation' option in 'exp build:ios'.
Guides used to create the certificates:

- [Here for the distribution certificate p12](https://calvium.com/how-to-make-a-p12-file/)
- [Here for the push notification certificate p12](https://www.mobiloud.com/help/knowledge-base/how-to-export-push-notification-certificate-p12/)
- [Here for the mobileprovision file](https://calvium.com/how-to-make-a-mobileprovision-file/)

Answer (score 0):

‘exp build:ios’ has a flag `--apple-enterprise-account` that will make things as enterprise and you won’t get that `Reason:You are not allowed to perform this operation.` message.